# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'- Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I have the following code in my functions.php thats is causing the error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'

PHP code:

```
function va_child_add_fax_field( $args ) {
$args['custom_fields']['fax'] = array( 'internal_key' =&gt; 'app_fax' );

return $args;
}
```

Please help
    add_filter( 'va_csv_importer_args', 'va_child_add_fax_field' );

Comment: Have you tried looking at the error? The error is very clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
$args['custom_fields']['fax'] = array( 'internal_key' => 'app_fax' );
```

Comment: Ohh no..I feel stupid..thanks alot